# Strange extra equal sign in mysql query. How do I remove it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to assign the `$updateNames` variable to accept 4 different values therefore allowing me to re-upload one file at a time. Right now whatever file I upload just gets put into `name1`.

Here is the php:

```
    <?php

require_once('storescripts/connect.php');
mysql_select_db($database_phpimage,$phpimage);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$uploadDir = 'upload/';
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{


foreach ($_FILES as $file)
{

    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $tmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];

    if ($fileName != ""){
        $filePath = $uploadDir;
        $fileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);

        //Split the name into the base name and extension
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($fileName);
        $fileName_base = $pathInfo['fileName'];
        $fileName_ext = $pathInfo['extension'];

        //now we re-assemble the file name, sticking the output of uniqid into it
        //and keep doing this in a loop until we generate a name that 
        //does not already exist (most likely we will get that first try)
        do {
           $fileName = $fileName_base . uniqid() . '.' . $fileName_ext;
        } while (file_exists($filePath.$fileName));

        $file_names [] = $fileName;

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath.$fileName);
    }


if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
$fileinsert[] = $filePath;
}
}

$mid   = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mid']));
$cat   = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['cat']));
$item  = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['item']));
$price = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['price']));
$about = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['about']));

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $values[$i] = isset($file_names[$i]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($file_names[$i]) : '';

    if($values[$i] != '')
    {
        $updateVals[] = "name".($i+1)." = '{$values[$i]}'";
    }

}
$updateNames = '';
if(count($updateVals))
{
    $updateNames = ", " . implode(', ', $updateVals);
}

$update = "INSERT INTO image
               (mid, cid, item, price, about, name1, name2, name3, name4)
           VALUES
               ('$mid', '$cat', '$item', '$price', '$about', '$values[0]', '$values[1]', '$values[2]', '$values[3]')
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                cid = '$cat', item = '$item', price = '$price', about = '$about' $updateNames";
$result = mysql_query($update) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your $fields array remains empty, while you populate the $values array. References therefore return an empty string, resulting in an incomplete assignment expression.

Comment: how would you suggest i assign a proper value to my $fields array?

Comment: Within each iteration of the loop, use something like $fields[$i]="name".($i+1);

Comment: where exactly would that be added?

Comment: i put it inside the $fields array like this $fields = array("name".($i+1)); now the $i is undifined

Comment: are you sure you wrote this code? you seem to be unfamiliar with even the basic structure and syntax of the language.

Comment: and you add the line before the 'if' statement block within the for loop that comes immediately after the declaration.

Comment: no if i added it there it would still throw the extra = $fields = array("name".($i+1)); at least assigns something

Comment: the problem isn't that the = sign is extra and unwanted. it's that what comes before is missing. by assigning the values for the $fields array, we are ensuring that the left-hand-side of that assignment exists, thereby making sense. please go through and understand the rest of this code (i am intentionally refraining from saying 'your') ... you will then understand your mistake.

Comment: i don't even need any array to do what i want i have updated MY code. the problem now isn't assigning a value it is that the value is only replacing $name1

Comment: you're right there. what i was trying to convey was one of _many_ possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: yes and i do think check boxes was an interesting solution that I am now using as it is better off than having no unique id. thanks

Comment: glad to help. apologies for doubting you, but i hope you understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic error there.

```
INSERT INTO image (mid, cid, item, price, about, name1, name2, name3, name4) VALUES ('167', 'hats', 'zzz', 'zz', 'zz', '4f64105aad275.jpg', '', '', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid = 'hats', item = 'zzz', price = 'zz', about = 'zz' , = '4f64105aad275.jpg';
```

At the very end of above statement, you've `, = '4f64105aad275.jpg'`. Please set it to: `, name1 = '4f64105aad275.jpg';`

Comment: You're updating your database, so you should know about which field to store what value. I just mentioned the error in SQL statement. Also, in your insert clause `VALUES ('167', 'hats', 'zzz', 'zz', 'zz', '4f64105aad275.jpg', '', '', '')` you've kept name 234 empty yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't assign any value to `$fields[]` array in the for loop.

You don't need an array to do what you want.

That should work:

```
$updateVals[$i] = "name".($i+1)." = '{$values[$i]}'";
```

You need to use i+1 as the name variables starts with 1.

Comment: now it just keeps replacing the first image with anything i upload

Comment: Edited the answer again. I'm not sure if it will work, don't have time to check the whole code, sorry.